# Why "cat" paramenter give me 404 NOT FOUND http error?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a very strange problem with wordpress.
I have this kind of pages:

```
http://www.example.it/page/4
```

if I visit:

```
http://www.example.it/page/4?cat=1
```

I get the **error 404 not found**

If I visit:

```
http://www.example.it/page/4?catt=1
```

I can see the page correctly.

Why does the cat paramenter returns this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cat is a parameter that is used internally by wordpress when parsing arguments. It is actually looking for a category of that kind.

A 404 will appear if no post has that category associated with that category ID.

If the category does exist then wordpress will redirect you to either a page or archive listing depending on what you have setup.

In short. Cat is reserved as a parameter.